# Converting initWithString from objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, initialization

I'm new to swift and objective C programming language. I am a bit confused as I have to migrate a code from objective C to swift.

The Objective C code is as follows:

```
- (name *)initWithString:(NSString *)name num:(NSNumber *)num {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.num = num;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)name num:(NSNumber *)num {
    return [[self alloc] initWithString:name num:num] ;
}
```

From my understanding till now, I've come to this part of swift:

```
func init(name: String?, num: NSNumber?) {
    super.init()
    self.name = name
    self.num = num

    return self
}

class func init(name: String?, num: NSNumber?) -> Self {
    return self.init(name: name, num: num)
}
```

But still, I'm confused as how to convert initWithString to the swift initializer. From the docs, I only got the basic syntax of it.

1. How to fix this?
2. What's the difference between initWithString and normal init?
3. I think `-` means instance method and `+` means static method. Can someone please brief it.

Comment: May I suggest reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book to get you started with swift. And don't look to much at the objective-c code and focus on swift instead.

Comment: Yes I did, and I noticed the mistake of writing func with init, that was my bad. I couldn't find about that we don't have to add static method as mentioned in answer by @DavidPasztor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your Swift code. First, when you create an `init`, there's no `func` keyword, `init` itself is the keyword that shows this is an `init` rather than a simple function. Second, there's no `return` statement in Swift initializers (unless it's a failable init, but even then you can only return nil to fail the init). You simply need to assign a value to all stored properties, there's no need to return self (unlike in Obj-C). There's also no need to call `super.init()`, since Swift classes don't need to inherit from a base class (unlike in Obj-C where `NSObject` is the base class).

There's also no need to add a static method, since in Swift you can call the init directly on the type name, like `let instance = Something(name: "name", num: 1)`.

So those 2 Obj-C methods translate to this in Swift:

```
class Something {
    let name: String?
    let num: NSNumber?

    init(name: String?, num: NSNumber?) {
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
    }
}
```

As for the question regarding the Obj-C code itself:

You got the difference between `-` and `+` right, `-` means instance method, while `+` means type method.

The difference between a normal init, `- (name *)initWithString:(NSString *)name num:(NSNumber *)num` and the type function `+ (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)name num:(NSNumber *)num` is that when you call an Obj-C init, you need to do `[[Type alloc] initWithString]`, while with the static method, there's no need to call `alloc`, you can simply call `[Type initWithString]`.

Comment: I would not use NSNumber and I am questioning if OP meant to have both arguments as optionals and that it is also part of the beginner mistakes

Comment: @David do we need something like ```class Something: NSObject{ ...} ``` ? And if not, when do we use that?

Comment: @Alohomora as I've said in my answer, no, Swift classes don't need to inherit from `NSObject`. In fact, they shouldn't inherit from it either, unless you want to be able to use the Swift class from Obj-C, in which case you need to do `@objc class Something: NSObject { ...`.